# Apply layer comp in linked smart object only to specific layer comps in root PSD?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, smartobject

I'm using Photoshop CC for UI design.

Let's say I've got 3 buttons as separate linked smart objects. Each button has a layer comp for a pressed and a not-pressed state.

I place the linked smart objects in my root PSD. What I'd like, is for there to be 3 layer comps in the root PSD. One for each button being pressed.

Is there a way to make this work using only 1 instance of each smart object in my root PSD?

Or do I need to have 2 instances of each smart object in my PSD (one for pressed and another for not pressed) and then hide/show the relevant layers to get the desired effect?

Thanks!

Comment: i havent found an answer to this, im in the same way and i think it's not possible :(

Answer (score 1):

I use fairly small amount of `Linked smart objects`, probably because I'm too used to not having that feature in photoshop, so I might not use this method myself, but to answer answer the question:

1. Have all button states inside one `Linked smart object` with some empty space between.
2. Create a `Layer mask` the size of one button. Preferably slightly larger than the button.
3. Unlink the `Layer mask`.
4. Create `Layer comps` for each button state, where you move the layer/button inside the visible area of the `Layer mask`.

[image]

The fact that I'm using a regular `Embedded smart object` in this example gif makes no difference.